# rsyslog ENABLE "last message repeated"?

Tags: rsyslog

I just built a new linux 3.7.6 kernel and have a built-in module (which is not in use) throwing errors as fast as it probably can, ie, reporting a busy loop.  Obviously this is not good and I have to deal with it, etc, but I would really -- really -- really -- really -- really -- really -- really appreciate it if rsyslog would not repeat the message on disk to the tune of 10MB/hour, etc.

I had thought syslog daemons prevented this by using "last message repeated" but that seems not to be the case.  I have no idea what this option would even be called, since *compression* is a hot bed of references.

Comment: Are they *identical* messages? "Last message repeated" on suppresses identical messages.

Comment: Oh they are very identical.  No component should do this, it's an (unused) network driver, it should just crap out at worst.  Anyway I found `$RepeatedMessageReduction` and will try that later.  It seems some years ago the rsyslog devs decided this feature (filtering duplicate messages) was not worth what it cost resource wise and may have depreciated it right out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm `$RepeatedMessageReduction` no longer works for rsyslog 5.8.10; ie, the "last message repeated" feature has been removed and there is no replacement.  Oh well.

Seems this probably happened a few years ago:

http://kb.monitorware.com/last-message-repeated-feature-will-go-away-t1720.html

http://lists.adiscon.net/pipermail/rsyslog/2008-March/000603.html

Answer (score 0):

What "builtin module that isn't used" is spewing messages? Most of the kernel messages that could repeat are printed a few times at most, so this looks like something nonstandard. Self compiled kernel, any special configuration? Debugging something perhaps?

Comment: No, in fact it is *ath9k* (atheros wireless); the config was the same as I used for 3.6.2 -- with ath9k built-in.  However, looking back through the logs it did happen once with 3.6.2, obviously I did not notice.  I think it has only happened when I use the wireless (it seems to work fine), which I don't often do with this box.  But I should report that, something wrong there.